# Why isn't the Beast Titan at the start of season 3?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Season 2 ended showing the characters, some titans and then on top of a far away wall the Beast Titan with the titan shifter outside him looking out, but now on season 3 there was only a brief mention of him.

Is the story continuing right after the previous episode or is there any time gap between them?

Will it go back to him any time soon in the next episodes?

Comment: I'm not sure since it's been a while since I read this part in the manga but I don't think the beast titan will be playing a role in this season, maybe being mentioned in the end. This season will focus more on the people inside the wall.

Comment: @Gravinco He's an interesting character so I would like to get to see more action with him. I guess I will have to wait to see if he does appear or not. I don't read the manga but since I have been a bit spoiled by my curiosity while browsing the site I guess its fine to get some manga info from your comment.

Comment: He will be appearing again but I don't think it'll be for this season, not sure tho since reading this has been a while ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expect the Beast Titan to appear very soon, this season of Attack On Titan will be very packed with its 24 episodes. The story is continuing after season 2's last episode, but there was a little time skip for both parties to kind of regen and recouperate from last episodes antics. Best way to enjoy this season and Attack On Titan is to stay far away from spoilers and let everything naturally unfold the way it should do.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

There is a time gap yes. If I remember right it was like one week or something like that.

Comment: I'm probably going to rewatch the new episode as I didn't paid enough attention. Hopefully we get to see more of that in upcoming episodes.

Answer (score 0):

There was a 3 week time gap between S2 finale and the start of the S3 premiere.

The beast titan was at Shiganshina, most likely preparing for the Survey Corps to come.

The Survey Corps did plan on going to the basement and sealing up the wall but because of recent complications with the Military police and Reiner/Bertolt, it was on delay.